# for some reason my data isn't being added to my file with my c function

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to create a small book library in C so I wrote a function that insert a book by it's name, id and quantity. For some reason the program is ruining fine and the function seems to be working but the external file remain unchanged (no new data is added). I checked the path of the file but still the problem persist. how can I fix this?

here's the function and the structure:

````
struct library{
int id;
int qty;
char name[50];
};
void InsertBook()
{
    struct library b;
    FILE *books;
    if((books=fopen("C:\\mybooks.txt","a+")==NULL))
    {
        printf("file not found\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You will need to enter a name, ID, and quantity of the book.\n");
        printf("please enter book name:");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(b.name,SIZE,stdin);
        fputs(b.name,books);
        printf("please enter book ID:");
        scanf("%d",&b.id);
        printf("please enter book quantity:");
        scanf("%d",&b.qty);
        fprintf(books,"%d %s %d\n",b.name,b.id,b.qty);
        fclose(books);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake you've done is:

```
fprintf(books, "%d %s %d\n", b.name, b.id, b.qty);
```

Just do:

```
fprintf(books, "%s %d %d\n", b.name, b.id, b.qty); // %s before %d
```

And everything's OK.

### Side Tips

- `fputs()` not required here.
- `books = fopen("C:\\mybooks.txt", "a+") == NULL` expression won't work for most compilers because the assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast.

  Instead you can assign it before comparing it to the null expression as shown:

  ````
  books = fopen("C:\\mybooks.txt", "a+");
  if (books == NULL) { ... }```
  ````

**Important note:** Ensure you have writing permission in that destination.

Answer (score 0):

The program does work (but see errors below), however you are writing to the root folder of Drive C. The output file is visible from a console, but not from Windows file explorer. Normally, you should not use the root folder of C drive.

There is a parenthesis in the wrong place here

```
if((books=fopen("mybooks.txt","a+")==NULL))
```

which should be

```
if((books = fopen("mybooks.txt","a+")) == NULL)
```

There are wrong format specifications wrong in `fprintf` here, as complained by the compiler

```
fprintf(books,"%d %s %d\n",b.name,b.id,b.qty);
```

should be

```
fprintf(books, "%s %d %d\n", b.name, b.id, b.qty);
```

You unnecessarily duplicate writing the book title to file a few lines above with

```
fputs(b.name,books);
```

You use an incorrect buffer size for `fgets` here

```
fgets(b.name,SIZE,stdin);
```

which should be

```
fgets(b.name, sizeof b.name, stdin);
```

Also, you must check the return values particularly from user input functions such as `fgets` and `scanf`.

---

Additionally there are faults waiting to happen with the input of the book title here

```
fgets(b.name, sizeof b.name, stdin);
```

- It retains the newline which will be part of the data. Please see  [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)
- When you make a loop to input more books, it will catch the newline left in the buffer by `scanf`. Please see Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

So I suggest you replace that line with

```
if(scanf("%49[^\n]", b.name) != 1)
    exit(1);
```

It is best not to mix the input methods: stick to one.